# Concrete floor/slab sealing

Tags: concrete, floor

I would like to have someone seal my concrete floor without grinding or etching. Can this be done?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by sealing.  Most people would just clean the floor good, dump a paint can on it and rolled it out and call it a day.  Grinding/etching are done when other work needs doing.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how filthy it is.

If it's more-or-less clean and not contaminated (oil, etc.) you can clean it well and expect success painting. Whether or not the sealant has pigment it's essentially painting, and floor paint is my "sealer" of choice, though your choice may vary.

If it has stuff that won't come off with soap and water and scrubbing, you may need to etch it to get a good bond for painting/sealing. Otherwise the paint/sealer may peel off, wasting the money spent on doing that job.

The only reason to grind is to change the shape or texture of the surface. So if you don't want to do those things, grinding should not be needed.

If it's new, virtually all products suggest waiting until it's a month old before coating. Check the label on the product you choose, and if need be, wait.